# How to pass Search Query to another activity using button search

Tags: java, php, android

i'm developing an android app for job search, here PHP as back end. The job list fetch from server and display as card view is working well.here i want search with location and job title . so how to pass my location and job title from search activity to job activity.

```
 private void searchjob() {

        final String title = jobtitle.getText().toString().trim();
        final String location = city.getSelectedItem().toString().trim();

        Intent intent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(title,1);
        intent.putExtra(location,2);


        startActivity(intent);
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in, R.anim.slide_out);
    }
```

This is my Download Card java class.

```
public class DownloaderCard extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, String> {
    Context c;
    String address;
    SwipeDeck swipeDeck;
    ProgressDialog pd;
    String url = "";

    public DownloaderCard(Context c, String address, SwipeDeck swipeDeck) {
        this.c = c;
        this.address = address;
        this.swipeDeck = swipeDeck;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pd = new ProgressDialog(c);
        pd.setTitle("Please Wait");
        pd.setMessage("Loading....");
        pd.show();
    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        String data = downloadData();
        return data;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        pd.dismiss();
        if(s!=null){
            //Toast.makeText(c, s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            ParserCard p = new ParserCard(c, s, swipeDeck);
            p.execute();
        }else {
            Toast.makeText(c, "Unable to download data from downloader", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
    private String downloadData(){
        InputStream is = null;
        String line = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(address);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            is = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
            if(br != null){
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null){
                    sb.append(line+"\n");
                }

            }else {
                return null;
            }
            return sb.toString();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if(is != null){
                try {
                    is.close();
                }catch (IOException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

This is my JobActivity.

```
String urlData = "https://www.joblist.php";

        final DownloaderCard dl = new DownloaderCard(MainActivity.this,urlData , cardStack);
        dl.execute();
        cardStack.setEventCallback(new SwipeDeck.SwipeEventCallback() {
            @Override
            public void cardSwipedLeft(int position) {
                // Log.i("MainActivity", "card was swiped left, position in adapter: " + position);
            }

            @Override
            public void cardSwipedRight(int position) {
                //   Log.i("MainActivity", "card was swiped right, position in adapter: " + position);
            }

            @Override
            public void cardsDepleted() {
                // Log.i("MainActivity", "no more cards");
            }

            @Override
            public void cardActionDown() {
                // Log.i(TAG, "cardActionDown");
            }

            @Override
            public void cardActionUp() {
                // Log.i, "cardActionUp");
            }

        });
        cardStack.setLeftImage(R.id.left_image);
        cardStack.setRightImage(R.id.right_image);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                cardStack.swipeTopCardLeft(180);

            }
        });

        btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                cardStack.swipeTopCardRight(180);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: you asked how to pass the data between two activities, but you already passed the data here `intent.putExtra(title,1);` what do you want to do now?

Comment: yes. but how to pass it php code

Answer (score 1):

Here is a method I use to send login information to a PHP server.. update it so it can fit your purpose.

```
      public String LoginOnService(String url,String email,String pass){
                InputStream inputStream = null;
                String result = "";
                try {

                    // 1. create HttpClient
                    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

                    // 2. make POST request to the given URL
                    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url+"?email="+email+"&password="+pass);
                    // 3. Execute POST request to the given URL
                    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
                    if(httpResponse != null){
                       result = EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity());
                    }else{
                       result = "Did not work!";
                    }
               } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.d("InputStream", e.getLocalizedMessage());
               }

               // 11. return result
               return result;
       }
```

As you can see I am passing a `String` but if you want to send data as `JSON`, you might benefit from these comments too. but in step 2 only pass a url `HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);`

```
 public String LoginOnService(String url,String email,String pass){
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        String result = "";
        try {

            // 1. create HttpClient
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            // 2. make POST request to the given URL
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url+"?email="+email+"&password="+pass);

//            String json = YOUR_JSON_STRING;

            // 3. build jsonObject
//            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
//            jsonObject.accumulate("Email", user.getEmail());
//            jsonObject.accumulate("Password", user.getPassword());

            // 4. convert JSONObject to JSON to String
//            json = jsonObject.toString();

            // ** Alternative way to convert Person object to JSON string usin Jackson Lib
            // ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            // json = mapper.writeValueAsString(person);

            // 5. set json to StringEntity
//            StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json);

            // 6. set httpPost Entity
//            httpPost.setEntity(se);

            // 7. Set some headers to inform server about the type of the content
//            httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
//            httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

            // 8. Execute POST request to the given URL
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httpPost);

//             9. receive response as inputStream
//            inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();

            // 10. convert inputstream to string
            if(httpResponse != null)
                result = EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity());
            else
                result = "Did not work!";

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("InputStream", e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }

        // 11. return result
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: i tried but its. not working.  please tell me how to pass search query to pass url

Comment: I am getting more confused here, so what do you mean by **search query**? do you mean the query that performs a search on the `PHP server`? check this link [Android Search View with PHP and MySQL](http://androidcss.com/android/android-search-view-php-mysql/)

Comment: in my home activity, there is 2 edit text ,location and job title and one button, i want to pass the title and location values into Job activity url..  http://alot.ae/api/joblist.php is my url so how can i pass the value into php url

Comment: try this in your browser, I will pass the values of **location** and **tittle** with the **url** you provided, `alot.ae/api/joblist.php?location=London&tittle=programmer` this should return the search result if you are handling it correctly in you PHP.

Comment: yes. its working but . i dont know to how to pass it android

Comment: Actually I don't understand why it didn't work in Android, supposing you passed the values with the url, it should return a result that contains the data you want. **I suggest you rewrite your question, explain it as you did in the comments**, so someone might see it and help. good luck.

Comment: the problem in passing values to url . from edit text

Comment: Irshad! in your last comment you say that you are not able to `getText()` from the `editTtext`, which is `String location = editText.getText();` is that really the problem you have? I am sure it is not.

Comment: Glad to know. if the answer worths sharing.. post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should use Volley https://github.com/google/volley for calling **`Http Requests`**, This Will Make Your Work Lot Easier,
Here Is An Example:-

```
    final String url = "https://www.joblist.php?title=MyJobTitle&location=London";

// prepare the Request
JsonObjectRequest getRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
    new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {   
                        // display response     
            Log.d("Response", response.toString());
        }
    }, 
    new Response.ErrorListener() 
    {
         @Override
         public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {            
            Log.d("Error.Response", response);
       }
    }
);

// add it to the RequestQueue   
queue.add(getRequest);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  final String title = jobtitle.getText().toString().trim();
        final String location = city.getSelectedItem().toString().trim();

 Intent intent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("job_title",title);
        intent.putExtra("city",location);
```

in JobActivity

```
 String myvalue= getIntent().getExtras("job_title");
 String myvalue2= getIntent().getExtras("city");
```

php code

final String url = "https://www.joblist.php?title="+myvalue+"&location="+myvalue2;